# Can't build .aab in Flutter using Gitlab CI

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gitlab-ci, android-app-bundle

Whenever the CI script runs, I get the following error:

> "Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this
> file was generated under /project/build, but the tool couldn't find
> it."

When using a computer, i can build the .aab without problems. This problem only happens in CI. That's my .gitlab-ci:

```
image: cirrusci/flutter:2.2.3

before_script:
  - flutter pub get

stages:
  - productionDO
  - appTestHeroku

productionDO:
  stage: productionDO
  only:
    - master 
  script:
    - flutter build appbundle --flavor productionDO -t lib/main_productionDO.dart
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./build/app/outputs/bundle/productionDORelease

appTestHeroku:
  stage: appTestHeroku
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - flutter build appbundle --flavor appTestHeroku -t lib/main_appTestHeroku.dart
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - ./build/app/outputs/bundle/appTestHerokuRelease
```

That's my buid.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eti.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        heroku {
            storeFile file('heroku.jks')
            storePassword System.getenv("DO_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword System.getenv("DO_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }

        production {
            storeFile file('production.jks')
            storePassword System.getenv("DO_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword System.getenv("DO_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"
        productFlavors {
            productionDO {
                dimension "app"
                resValue "string", "app_name", "productionDO"
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                        appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                ]
            }
    
            appTestHeroku {
                dimension "app"
                resValue "string", "app_name", "herokuApp"
                applicationId "com.eti.app.heroku"
                manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_debug",
                ]
            }
        }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.heroku
        }

        release {
            productFlavors.appTestHeroku.signingConfig signingConfigs.heroku
            productFlavors.productionDO.signingConfig signingConfigs.production   
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for the exactly same problem in an Azure DevOps pipeline.
While i do not fully understand why the problem only occurs in a CI pipeline, it seems to be a flutter bug.
I was able to solve the problem, by applying the workaround suggested in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92316)